# Receiving "no such file or directory" error within a for loop - recognizes file initially

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

Code below:

```
for WorkingFile in os.listdir(path):  
    print(WorkingFile)
    xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(WorkingFile)
```

returns this:

```
ChetworthPark_Test.xlsx
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ChetworthPark_Test.xlsx'
```

So it's printing the file name (demonstrating that it recognizes the path), but then not passing it to the variable "xlsx" after. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong? For more context, I'm running this in Google Colab.

Comment: Try to add the path to your filename...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns the *file name* not the path. So you need to prepend the path:

```py
for fn in os.listdir(path):
   do_something(f"{path}/{fn}")
```

As pointed out in a comment, `/` for paths is not universal, so we have `os.path.join`:

```py
from os.path import join
for fn in os.listdir(path):
    fn = join(path, fn) # handles / or \
    do_something(fn)
```

However for a fair while now we've had `pathlib.Path` which makes this much easier:

```py
from pathlib import Path
for fn in os.listdir(path):
    do_something(Path(path) / fn)
```

or, more naturally with pathlib:

```py
from pathlib import Path
for fn in Path("/path/to/look/at").expanduser().resolve().glob("*"):
    if not fn.is_file():
        continue
    do_something(fn)
```

(note that I've also handled expanding things like `~/some-file` and simplifying the path here)

Comment: You might want to use `os.path.join` instead of hardcoding the forward slash, in case OP is using Windows.

Comment: fair point.  will update

Comment: Awesome! that worked perfectly. TIL about string literals as well

Comment: @SRed2 excellent; feel free to accept if it clears things up.  Note that I really would use pathlib for everything: messing with strings *will* go wrong sooner or later